# MBP Mid 2010 crashes with single color on screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, crash

My laptop crashes and displays colourful screens:
Red, orange, purple, green, pink, white, black.

I then have to shut it down for a couple of hours for it to work a while more. Does anyone know what could be causing the issue and how to solve it? It's a MacBook Pro Mid 2010.

[image]

Comment: Could you expand your question? What model of MacBook are you using? Could you provide pictures of the screen?

Comment: I ve edited my post

Comment: If you know how to it, publish a console report at the time stamp of the event, about 20-30 line. That might tell us who is doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the pictures and combining this with the fact that the screen reverts back to normal after turning off the laptop for a few hours, I suspect a hardware problem. Which means that you need to get the laptop to the next Apple Store (or other Apple dealer) to have it fixed.